# Remove a file extension case-insentively in Bash

Tags: bash, file-extension

I want to remove the suffix of a file by using `basename` in a Bash script.
The command removes the suffix only in a case-sensitive way though.

How can I remove a extension case-insensitively?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to remove an extension in Bash, you can do this without external tools. Then, pass it to `basename`:

```
$ f=/path/to/some/file.foo.bar
$ basename "${f%.*}"
file.foo
```

With a mixed-case extension:

```
$ f=/path/to/some/file.foo.Bar
$ basename "${f%.*}"
file.foo
```

Here, `%` is [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). It will remove the shortest matching substring from the back of what's in `f`. The `.*` matches a dot and zero or more characters, regardless of their case.

Answer (score 5):

Use parameter expansion

```
file=/home/johndoe/cv.DOC
basename ${file%.[Dd][Oo][Cc]}
```

Comment: That assumes you *know* the extension. This wouldn't work for all cases, and especially not with different kinds of files.